# Float:right reverses order of spans

Tags: css

I have the HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="label"><a href="/index/1">Bookmix Offline</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
span.button {
    float:right;
}

span.label {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

In the browser, spans display in the reverse order:  Import Export Settings.
Can I change the order by changing only the CSS file and leave the HTML as is?

Comment: I have tested all the answers here, and none work such that the label is on the LHS and the other spans 'flipped' on the RHS without changing markup. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18243885/703717

Comment: This was useful for me, in several occasions -> [flex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920265/horizontal-menu-how-to-float-right-but-keep-the-menu-items-in-the-correct-order/47119089#47119089)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The general solution to this problem is either to reverse the order of the right floated elements in the HTML, or wrap them in a containing element and float that to the right instead.

Comment: He said *"Can I change the order by changing only css-file and **left html as is**?"*

Comment: I prefer encompassing answers which give an overview of the solution in the relevant domain, which people use, providing a sense of where the actual answer fits it.

Comment: @Marcus: That's fine, but when the questioner has given a *specific constraint*, you can't really just ignore it.

Comment: @T.J. My answer contains a viable css only fix, floating the parent container to the right.

Comment: @Marcus: Whatever. *"...or wrap them in..."* reads like suggesting changing the HTML, esp. as you've suggested changing it in the first half of your sentence.

Comment: @T.J. understood, the answer could be more centred around the actual answer in the strictest sense. But I wanted to convey the point that, no actually you need to put some thought into the semantic layout of the HTML in order to take full advantage of CSS.

Comment: @Marcus: *"...you need to put some thought into the semantic layout of the HTML in order to take full advantage of CSS."* Very well said. I may steal that. :-)

Comment: Sake... I was searching for ages for a way to resolve the order in CSS it never occurred me to to just switch the HTML elements around. Simple but brilliant haha (y)

Comment: @MarcusWhybrow Well said... "...you need to put some thought into the semantic layout of the HTML in order to take full advantage of CSS."

Not only that but that tabbing order gets affected as well and this is very important for accessibility. I think the cleanest approach would be to have the HTML in the correct tabbing order first from left to right, etc, and then floating it with a mix of a float or flex.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to make your list items aligned right without reversing the order **dont float** your list items. Make them **inline** instead. text-align:right your **span**

```
div {
    text-align:right;
}

span {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Or you could use `display: inline-block;` to get the padding right

Answer (score 14):

**Yes, this can be done with your exact markup.**

**The trick is to use `direction: rtl;`**

### Markup

```
<div>
    <span class="label"><a href="/index/1">Bookmix Offline</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    direction: rtl;   
}

span.label {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp4Yt/1/)**

Comment: and that it affects pseudo elements too

Comment: Don't forget to reset the direction for any child elements: `div > * { direction: ltr }`.

Comment: This hack is too fragile. Better to float a parent container.

Answer (score 5):

```
div.outerclass {
  text-align: right;
}

div.outerclass .label {
  float: left;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: +1, but presumbly not **all** divs. :-) So this leaves the issue of how to adequately target the div without modifying the HTML. Hopefully there's enough structure that hasn't been shown to make it possible.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed the html in my question. I have one more span (class=label) which must be on the left side of screen.

Comment: Edited accordingly to both comments.

Comment: All four links places on the left side.

Answer (score 5):

very easy!

```
div.outerclass {
    float: right;
}

div.innerclass {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Update: Two lightweight CSS solutions:

Using [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), [**flex-flow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) and [**order**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order):

### [Example1: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m37cxb9g/1/)

```
    div{
        display:flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    span:nth-child(1){
        order:4;
    }
    span:nth-child(2){
        order:3;
    }
    span:nth-child(3){
        order:2;
    }
    span:nth-child(4){
        order:1;
    }
```

Alternatively, reverse the Y scale:

### [Example2: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m37cxb9g/4/)

```
div {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
span {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Example #2 is a nice solution for my case too, where I am floating list elements to the right, they're inline-block, and sporadically I am clearing between list items. My source order is thus reversed with float right. Your approach reverses the reversal while retaining the right float.

Comment: Note that using `order` only changes visual rendering order and may have problems with accessibility.

Answer (score 3):

Just use display:inline-block and text-align:right instead of float:right:

```
div { text-align:right }

span { display:inline-block }
```

Comment: This is the answer as per the exact question -- in some cases, you can only supply custom CSS for HTML content that is not in your control.

Answer (score 2):

Float the div right instead of the span elements?

Comment: +1, but there's the issue of how to adequately target the div without modifying the HTML. Hopefully there's enough structure that hasn't been shown to make it possible.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed the html in my question. I have one more span (class=label) which must be on the left side of screen.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the flex display

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="label"><a href="/index/1">Bookmix Offline</a></span>
  <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
  <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
  <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your updated question:

```
path to div {
    text-align: right;
}
path to div span.label {
    float: left;
}
```

I say "path to div" above because you need to adequately target this one div, which doesn't (according to your quoted code) have a class or ID of its own. That's not a problem if we can do it with structure.

So for instance, if the `div` is the only div within a container with the id (say) "navigation", that might be:

```
#navigation div {
    text-align: right;
}
#navigation div span.label {
    float: left;
}
```

Or if there are other divs in the container, but this is the only one that's 
a **direct child** of the navigation container, you can use a child selector instead of a descendant selector:

```
#navigation > div {
    text-align: right;
}
#navigation > div span.label {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works without rearranging the html and is very simple. Heres a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dzk7c/2/

html:

```
<div>
    <span class="label"><a href="/index/1">Bookmix Offline</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
</div>
```

and css:

```
div {
    float:right;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to toot my own horn, but my solution actually solves the answers question unlike the chosen answer by @MArcus which suggests you must rearrange the html which is not the case. Please correct me if I am wrong no hard feelings of course.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this, for someone...

http://jsfiddle.net/15abbg81/

only horizontal, may be to use: rtl/ltr of tables
should work in all browsers that support table-cell css

normal:

```
<div class="container">
    <section>1</section>
    <article>2</article>
    <aside> <span>א</span><span>.</span> </aside>
</div>
<style>
.container { display: table; 
    direction:ltr; /*ltr here is not required*/
    }
.container>* {
    display: table-cell; /*only works with table-cell*/
    direction:ltr; /*ltr here is not required*/
}
</style>
```

reverse:

```
<div class="reverse">
    <div class="container">
        <section>1</section>
        <article>2</article>
        <aside> <span>א</span><span>.</span> </aside>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .reverse .container { display: table;  direction:rtl } /*change the outside direction to rtl*/
    .reverse .container>* {
        display: table-cell;
        direction:ltr /*inside switch back to ltr if needed*/
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be achieved using flex margin positioning. Please note that this will work only on IE10+

```
div
{
    display: flex;  
}

span.label {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}

span.button {    
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get also stuck with this... so here is my sollution

I had this [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUvSA.png) and want this [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4ar.png)

HTML looks like this

```
<ul class="visible-xs restaurant-thumbnail__tags list-inline">
    @foreach($restaurant->categories as $category)
        <li>{{ $category->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
    @foreach($restaurant->labels as $label)
        <li>{{ $label->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

CSS looks like this

```
.restaurant-thumbnail__tags {
    direction: rtl;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.restaurant-thumbnail__tags li {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
div{ 
    width:300px; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
}
li{
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 5px;
    padding:5px;
    width:25px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing span into li, please explain the answer as well?

Answer (score -1):

you would need to float the spans left, and float the parent container right.

this will depend on the kind of layout you are trying to achieve however.

it's intended behaviour, for the benefit of screen readers and the like I imagine.  the other option is to adjust the mark-up, but this, as you say, may not be desirable.