# Horizontal menu: how to float right but keep the menu items in the correct order?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `float: right` for my horizontal menu (.drop_menu li) as I want the menu to be aligned to the right side of the screen (and logo to the left side). It works OK, the only issue is that my menu items are now in the wrong order (Link 3 then Link 3 then Link 1 instead of the opposite). Is there a way to fix that?
Many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">Logo</div>                            
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
        </div>


.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 120px;
    display: table;
     position: fixed;
        z-index: 999999;
        opacity: 0.7;
    background: aqua;
}

.logo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
left:0;
color: #333;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 800;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-left: 60px;
background: red;
}

 .drop_menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;

    right: 0;
    display: table;
    z-index: 3000;
       display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 0;

}


.drop_menu li { display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; float: right;}

.drop_menu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;



}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555; }
```

Comment: Change them round the other way, as in furthest right first and furthest left last

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `float:right` from `li` which prevent the reverse order.

Add `float:right` to the ul's `.dropdown` class which put your entire menu at right side.

Add `float:left` to the `li` which helps your sub-menu to stay align.

```
.drop_menu {
    float: right;  
}
.drop_menu li { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/2/)

Answer (score 4):

## `flex` solution:-

This is what worked for me:

```css
ul {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: flex-end;
     }
    
    
 ul li {
   outline: 2px violet solid;
   display: list-item;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 0 5px;
 }

ul li:hover {
   outline: 2px deeppink solid;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div>
      <h1>Hello World....</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Baz</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/appsparkler/emjst7f3/4/

Good Luck...

Answer (score 2):

Add one more div around menu items and set float to right

```
<div style='float:right'>
<!-- put menu controls here -->
</div>
```

Remove float right from following class

```
.drop_menu li { display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

for demo click on [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
.drop_menu li { display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle; float: left;
    }
```

It results in **LINK 1 LINK 2 LINK 3** order and reduce the width of submenu links.
It works.

Answer (score -1):

Float the `<ul>` to the right, then float its `<li>` elements to the left.