# How to make images float to the right while staying in order

Tags: html, css

I have three images that I'd like to float to the right side of a div.

```
<div>
  <img src="one_cat.jpg"></img>
  <img src="two_cats.jpg"></img>
  <img src="three_cats.jpg></img>
</div>
```

I've added a `float: right` property to them...

```
img {
    float: right;
}
```

... and while this puts them on the proper side, it also reverses their order.

[image: three_two_one_cats]

Here's my [code](http://codepen.io/d-H-/pen/bafAl).

How I can float them to the right of their div, while also keeping them in the order in which I've declared them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float the div container/wrapper instead of the images

```
div {
   float: right;
   display: inline-block; /* might want to add this too , but not necessary */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float from the *img*, and add the text-align to the *div*:

```
div {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: He may want the images to float to the right of the text

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
#images {
  float: right;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
```

And put the images inside div #images.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4224500/3413122).

It suggests either changing the order in which you list your images, or wrap them in another element (like the div you have) and float that right.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this rules

```
div{
    text-align:right;
}
div img{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Change the text align of the div and you can play with the position of the images, like text-align:center, and add some margin to the images.