# How to make a large set of images float to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a large set of image thumbnails, and I want to images to float to the right of their div.

I first tried to do this setting a `float: right` property on each image. This positioned them correctly, but mixed up their order, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22366811/765287).

A partial solution to the problem is to float the individual images to the *left* while placing them inside a container div that floats right. This partial solution is implemented [here](http://codepen.io/d-H-/pen/uDEzk).

The problem with this partial solution is that it only works when the window is sufficiently wide. If the window is large enough to accommodate all the images on a single line, they will appear flush with the div's right edge.

[image]

When the window is narrower, however, the images retreat to the left edge.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can ensure that the images stay aligned with the right edge of the div, even when the images span multiple lines?

Comment: This is normal that floating to right is reversing the order, cause your are making a stack of the images from the right of your div. This is surely the best solution, maybe you have just to reverse the order you display it to get it in the order you want, does that matter ?
In other cases, you may should use JavaScript to position them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the images as `inline-block` instead of floating, and setting their container to `text-align: right`, which affects inline elements as well as text.

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/piKcs)

Be aware, as with almost all of CSS, there are issues with support for `inline-block` on older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your images are set like this :

```
<ul class="images">
    <li><img src="" alt="Image 1"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="Image 2"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="Image 3"></li>
</ul>
```

Then set the style like this :

```
.images {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.images li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```