# Why menu created with ul li elements displayed in reverse order?

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu using `ul` and `li`, but it shows me in reverse order. For example:

**FAQ PRICING TOUR HOME** instead of the expected **HOME TOUR PRICING FAQ**

```
.header ul {

}
.header li {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin-left: 40px;
   float: right;
}

<div class="header">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TOUR</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PRICING</a></li>
      <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: It's because you're floating them `right`

Comment: @billyonecan Might as well make that an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should float only the `ul` right. The list items should be floated left in the correct (expected) order:

```
.header ul {
    float:right;
}

// expected order. It's the default value if not overriden,
// therefore it is not realy needed
.header li
{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of taking float right take it as left then you will get the result **HOME TOUR PRICING FAQ**

To understand it let us see :

Here you are trying to print **HOME TOUR PRICING FAQ** and if you will float this to the right it means you are telling to print from right and that's why it gives you the output as 
**FAQ PRICING TOUR HOME** so that's why we use `float: left;`

```
.header ul

{


}
.header li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;

}

 <div class="header">
         <ul>
            <li><a  href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">TOUR</a></li>
                 <li><a  href="">PRICING</a></li>
                <li><a  href="">FAQ</a></li>

            </ul>
  </div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yiduzece/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're floating each list element `right`.

Set `float: right` on the parent element instead.

```
.header ul {
  float: right;
}
```

There are various other solutions, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224476/span-float-reverse-order)

#### [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrcqr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons seems to be the float element. When you give `float:right`, it takes the first element to the right most side and rest of the items after that. However if you give `float:left`, the items seems to come in correct order with positioning the first item in the left and rest of the items after that.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    .header ul {
        float: right;
    }
    .header li {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 40px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Reason

you are floating `li` element to `right` so instead `float` it to `left`.

float `li` parent element ie `ul` to `left`.