# Margin and padding not working in nth-last-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have to display last two number 6 and 7 on the right side and it is displaying but there is no space between two number I need equal space. I tried margin and padding but not working. would you help me in this?

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p a:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try inverting 6 and 7 and using float right in the p elements, if that works for you.
Something like this:

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: red;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to write `display: block;` if you are using `float`

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Alien. It's working for me. I missed float: right;
Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side

Comment: Good point. But it was already there, I just forgot to remove it. Hehe..

Answer (score 2):

The overlap is cause by the `position: absolute`. One way to solve this is to use `flexbox`

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.p {
  display: flex;
}
.p p {
  color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
.p p a {
  color: red;
}
.p p:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using flex you can try this:

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.p {
  display: flex;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.p p a:nth-last-child(n-2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.ovokuro.It is also working for me. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

You can use non breaking space too

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p a:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn">&nbsp;<img src="" />6 &nbsp;</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(1){
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.p p:nth-last-child(2){
 position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(-n+2) a {
  color: red;  
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="" class="btn"><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code. don't have to exchange last two p class value.

```
<style>
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(1){
    position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.p p:nth-last-child(2){
    position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(-n+2) a {
  color: red;  
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin and padding is working well on nth-child.

Your problem is about positions ...

Solution 1:

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p p {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.p p a {
  color: blue;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  float: right;
}

.p p:nth-last-child(-n+2) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="p">
    <p><a href="">1</a></p>
    <p><a href="">2</a></p>
    <p><a href="">3</a></p>
    <p><a href="">4</a></p>
    <p><a href="">5</a></p>

    <p>
      <a href=""><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href=""><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand why I reverse the two lastest elements : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224476/floatright-reverses-order-of-spans)

Solution 2:

```css
.width-60 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.width-60 .left p,
.width-60 .right p {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.width-60 .left {
  float: left;
}

.width-60 .left a {
  color: blue;
}

.width-60 .right {
  float: right;
}

.width-60 .right a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-60">
  <div class="left">
    <p><a href="">1</a></p>
    <p><a href="">2</a></p>
    <p><a href="">3</a></p>
    <p><a href="">4</a></p>
    <p><a href="">5</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>
      <a href=""><img src="" />6</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href=""><img src="" />7</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.