# Display unordered list elements in correct order

Tags: html, css

I've got a very simple `CSS` problem, which I'm getting nowhere with.

I'm expecting the header-right div to be displayed like this:

```
a b c d
```

Instead it shows like this:

```
d c b a
```

How do I get this aligned in the order I expect?

```css
    ul li{
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #header {
     width: 100%;
    }

    #header-left li {
      float: left;
    }

    #header-right li {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 25px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="header">
    <div id="header-left">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Brand</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/a">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="/b">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="/c">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="/d">d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `float:right` on the `li`, just on `#header-right`

Comment: you already made the `li` tp be inline, it should be enoght ... use float of their parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Float:right reverses order of spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224476/floatright-reverses-order-of-spans)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes that works, thank you but removing the float right makes the header-right list show beside the header-left list.  I need the brand name on the left and a small nav on the right.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing in [the code posted by G-Cyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877040/215552)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are floating the `li` to the right. The browser starts floating elements in the order it sees them. What that means is: `a` gets moved to the right, then `b` gets moved to the right, then `c`, and finally `d`.

Float your `ul` instead.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header-left ul {
  float: left;
}

#header-right ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Brand</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/a">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="/b">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="/c">c</a></li>
      <li><a href="/d">d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use flexbox to solve this problem.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Pushes #header-left and #header-right to the outside edges of #header. */
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

#header-right ul {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Brand</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/a">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="/b">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="/c">c</a></li>
      <li><a href="/d">d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

do not float lis, only ul :

```css
ul li{
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
 width: 100%;
}

#header-left  {
  float: left;
}

#header-right  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div id="header-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Brand</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="header-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/a">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="/b">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="/c">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="/d">d</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

grid or flex will do the job too :

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right:25px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header, #header-right ul {
  display: flex;
}

#header-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Brand</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="header-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/a">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="/b">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="/c">c</a></li>
      <li><a href="/d">d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your float right on the li is your issue. This will fix it:

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
}

#header-left li {
  float: left;
}

#header-right {
  float: right;
}

#header-right li {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```