# How do I sort the list or other items using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do the following with CSS and do the same with JS?

[image: The picture shows what I want.]

I want in a similar way:

```js
var f = document.getElementsByClassName("f-right");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
  f[i].style.cssFloat = "right";
}
```

```css
.list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<p>As I "managed":</p>

<ul class="list">
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li class="f-right">list item 2</li>
  <li class="f-right">list item 3</li>
  <li class="f-right">list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: It's unclear what is your issue and what you really want as result. What's wrong with your code? And why do you use JS for a CSS task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224476/floatright-reverses-order-of-spans

Comment: "How can I do the following with CSS and do the same with JS?"  How is JavaScript involved? You mean how to not put it on the first item? Do not start at 0 and not sure what cssFloat is

Comment: flex has been around for a few years now , you should have heard of it.  you could do : `ul{display:flex;} li:first-of-type{margin-right:auto;}`

Comment: @epascarello [That's how you used to have to set the "float" CSS property via JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) (see the Note). `float` is a reserved word, so just like you have to set `className`, or `htmlFor`, you'd have to set `style.cssFloat` (IE had `styleFloat` just to be contrary). Of course, modern browsers use `float`, but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is helpful for these scenarios. Cheers

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: red 1px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: green 1px solid;
}

li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
</ul>
```